# Wiring a single pole switch next to a 3-way switch

Tags: wiring, switch

I am doing a kitchen remodel and I would like to wire a new single pole switch to an additional light.  See the attached diagram (the new single pole switch is labelled *2 way*).  This is exactly what is going on in my kitchen.  I would like to know if I can get supply power from the 3-way switch at the end of the current circuit.
[image]
Thank You!

Comment: Your usage of "2-way" is confusing in this context.  Do you mean a standard single switch that controls one light?  Is the light new?

Comment: Basically I need to know if I can get a power source from the existing circuit that is in the same gang box.

Comment: If your box only has one set of black, white, and red ( or just three wires in general), you will not be able to get constant voltage from any pair of wires.  If there are other wires in the box that happen to be bundled together, you might have a chance.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot extend the circuit from that location. You could extend the circuit from the first switch location, or run additional wires to the second switch location.

The location you've highlight lacks  a grounded (neutral) conductor, and an unswitched ungrounded (hot) conductor.

Comment: That's kind of what I thought.  thank you so much for your help!